# string literals in PHP

Tags: php, string, escaping

in C# you can declare a literal string that you don't expect to have any escaping in it like:

```
string myString = @"This\is\some\string\";
```

For PHP is there anyway to declare a string literal in this way without needing to escape every slash? I know someone out there will ask me "what have you tried?" so for the sake of completeness I will list what doesn't work:

```
$myString = "This\is\some\string\";
$myString = 'This\is\some\string\';
```

Comment: Your last slash is escaping the string delimiter. That's why they don't work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php documents the four options you have...

Comment: @JohnConde  dude I know this. thats why I'm asking

Comment: I think this question is real... don't know why it is flagged. Unless it is asked somewhere else on SO.

Comment: It's a good question. Rust has r#. Join the 20s PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes and you should be good (less single quotes of course).  If you really don't want to have to escape anything try [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

**EDIT:** assuming PHP >=5.3 (thank you Sammitch)

Comment: note: NOWDOCs are only as recent as PHP 5.3, HEREDOCS work similarly with the exception variable expansion working within them.

Answer (score 1):

as sequoia mcdowell pointed out [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)/[newdocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) are the answer. like so:

```
$myString = <<<'EOT'
This\is\some\string\
EOT;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with something like ```A¿!GÄ±t¦u5!ÙÓS|R``` like quotes kinda does but with still requiring escapes.